# Should we prefer questions with accepted answers when closing identification requests as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions, duplicate-questions, story-identification

A couple of days ago, [a story ID request](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186821/19561) was closed as a duplicate of [another one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/88080/19561).

Both have an answer which is correct, according to the querant.

But I saw that the one that was closed as a duplicate had an *accepted* answer, while the other one did not — just a confirmation in a comment.

**Shouldn't we prefer to make the one *without* an accepted answer a duplicate of the one *with* an accepted answer?**

---

*This question is both about the specific questions and the general principle.*

Comment: As long as it is confirmed by the OP I don't think it matters, the OP might not even know you can accept an answer. Look to see which has the best Q/A and use that as the target.

Comment: Highly related, possible dupe: [When should comments be used to determine a dupe story-id?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10278/when-should-comments-be-used-to-determine-a-dupe-story-id)

Comment: @Edlothiad not a dupe; I'm asking in which direction the duplicity should be resolved if one question has an accepted answer while the other one only has confirmation in a comment.

Comment: Given it says "yep comments just as good" I'd say it doesn't matter.

Comment: Looking at the example, I would have chosen the one with the more complete answer which didn't require me to go to another site for further enhancement. Even though one had an accepted answer, the second one was more "complete" thus I had no problem looking at the quality of the answer vs the number of upvotes. Quality is job one, after all.

Comment: @Edlothiad: Please do not answer in the comments.  Comments cannot be properly voted on and are impermanent.

Comment: @kevin - Also, "we've already answered this elsewhere" is less of an answer and more of a comment.

Comment: Edlothiad, yep definitely not a dupe. @TheLethalCarrot, want to post that as an answer to be voted on?

Comment: @Kevin I don't think linking to a related question really counts as an answer ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor: I was referring to the *second* comment by Edlothiad.

Comment: If this is about story-id specifically (I don't see why it wouldn't be) it should say so in the title.

Comment: @SQB seems perfect enough to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No

Comments are fine to be used for closing as a duplicate, all that matters is that we have confirmation. This is because not all users know that you can accept an answer, especially new users (and we get a lot of story id questions from them).

#### So what criteria should we use when closing?

The short answer to this is whichever question has the best Q/A.

- A well written, focused question with a lot of detail.
- A well written answer:

  - Addresses the OP's points
  - Has some general description
  - Has an image of the book cover/trailer link etc.
  - Includes links to somewhere with more information
- Has less noise i.e. fewer comments asking for clarification and fewer incorrect answers

Obviously not all those points need to be met but they give a general guideline of what to look for, for the better Q/A. For more information see: [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/58193) and [How to write a good story-ID answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193)

Comment: I'd never heard of the "less noise" criteria, but it does make sense.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It's certainly lower on the "things to look at" scale but it could be worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

My take on this is that an accepted answer has more permanence than a comment. Of course, the querant who accepted the answer can de-accept it, but *anyone* can flag a comment for deletion.

While [a comment confirming a correct answer is enough to allow for closure as a duplicate](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10278/19561), I think when given the choice between two question of which only one has an actual accepted answer while does not, we should close as a duplicate the one that does not have an accepted answer, in favour of the question that does have one.

Comment: I'm not certainly that I entirely agree here, although I can see your point. Personally, I've been trying to quote the accepting comment when I do get an answer accepted that way. :-P Admittedly, I don't know how well I've done objectively there...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots that's one of the good ways of doing it. Mods will always be able to read the deleted comments (although unable to undelete them if their user deleted) so quoting should be sufficient, I usually try to point to the comment by writing another comment under the question suggesting they accept the answer by pressing the green checkmarlk.