# Not a dupe closed as dupe

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I asked a question specifically looking for a canon source to [Vogon Poet's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221781/89771) claim that humans are immune to Pokemon attacks.

[Are humans officially immune to Pokemon attacks?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223182/are-humans-officially-immune-to-pokemon-attacks?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I clearly linked to the original question, yet it was closed as a dupe. Although Vogon Poet's answers the original question by providing examples, he provides no evidence.

The original question asked if Pokemon breeding provides resistance. My question asks if all humans are immune to Pokemon. They are in no way similar questions.

Comment: The answer to that question directly answers your question. Could you explain what you're hoping to gain (in terms of knowledge) from getting it re-opened?

Comment: @Valorum Canon evidence

Comment: That sounds like something you should ask Vogon Poet in a comment, not in an entirely new question.

Comment: @Valorum Since it wasnt addressed in the orignal question I have the right to ask it as a new one.

Comment: I personally interpretted your question as 'This question exists, do we have any more evidence on the answer'. As such, I flagged it to be closed. If you want a better answer, you should raise a bounty on the original question. Personally, I think Vogons answer was welp written, and answered the question you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about [pokemon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon) itself. In particular, I don't know the answer to either of the two questions involved here, so I'm going to cover all possibilities.

- **If it's true that humans are immune to Pokemon attacks**, then that (with canon evidence) would be the answer to your question and also the older question. In this case, we could potentially close the older question as a duplicate of yours, because "are handlers immune" is covered by the more general "are humans immune".
- **If handlers have some immunity but humans in general do not**, then your question and the older question have two different answers, and neither of them should be closed as a duplicate of the other.
- **If not even handlers have protection from Pokemon attacks**, then that (again, with canon evidence) would be the answer to the older question and would also resolve your question. In that case, we could potentially close your question as a duplicate of the older one which would solve it completely.

I don't know which of these three options is the case - and it seems neither does the site at large, so far. The only answer we have so far is sitting at a net -1 (at the time of writing), and it says "*I believe within Pokémon canon Pokémon powers are simply ineffective against humans, so trainers need no special resistance.*" If true, this would be an answer to the question, but it's not really shown conclusively there, and the community doesn't seem to like this answer much.

So we're at the stage where there are two strongly related but slightly different questions. The answer to one of them *might* also answer the other, but we don't know for sure whether the correct answer to the older one *will* answer yours or not. Until we're sure, we should **err on the side of leaving the questions open**. Then if someone knows the answer, they can answer whichever one is likely to be the dupe *target* (as in, the correct answer to that one necessarily resolves the other one).

---

This specific case is a bit more complicated than just "are handlers immune" vs "are humans immune", because your question is not just an unrelated "are humans immune" but *specifically asking about a claim made in an answer to the older question*. **If that answer is edited to include canon proof, then your question becomes completely obsolete** and could indeed be closed. But if the answer is incorrect, then your question is a good one. We really need to wait and find out - but in the meantime, and in case the answerer doesn't return to edit their answer, there's no need to block your question from other answers.

---

Cf. the following hypothetical situations:

- I ask the question "Did Bellatrix Lestrange love Lord Voldemort?" and get an answer "Yes, because all Death Eaters loved Voldemort - it's part of the job description". That shouldn't be enough to close "Did Lucius Malfoy love Voldemort?" or "Did all Death Eaters love Voldemort?" as a duplicate, because that answer is *not correct*.
- I ask the question "Did Ron Weasley have two pets/familiars at the same time?" and get an answer "No, because Hogwarts students are allowed at most one [with evidence]", then a later question "Can Hogwarts students have more than one familiar?" would already be answered there (although I'd then argue for closing the specific case to the general, potentially merging to preserve answers).

Comment: So can we reopen it?

Answer (score 0):

Questions are not closed as duplicates because they are identical, but because they have the same answer.

Therefore are different ways this can happen, but very common is for an earlier specific question to be given a general answer that covers a later generalisation of the *question*.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6953/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6952/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11824/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6427/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1832/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9748/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3209/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/100430 https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10603/100430

Comment: How do we know if questions have the same answer?

Comment: This totally isn't how duplicates are supposed to work across the network.  Questions should only be closed as dupes if they are essentially _asking_ the same thing.  That's why you flag it as a duplicate question, not as a question that can lead to duplicate answers.